# Ignore line directives during compilation

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to get GCC to compile a program and ignore `#line` directives when printing error messages?

Comment: Well, you *could* `grep -v "^#line"` on the sources, but that's a bit.... rude. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to ignore them, but you can suppress their generation using the `-P` flag.